# my custom layout.xml file is not calling in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, php-5.4

my custom layout file is not calling, I configured backend also.

in my controller `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());` I debug it it is returning like this

```
array(5) {
  [0] => string(7) "default"
  [1] => string(13) "STORE_default"
  [2] => string(31) "THEME_frontend_easylife_default"
  [3] => string(16) "test_index_index"
  [4] => string(19) "customer_logged_out"
}
```

and I store log from `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout\Update.php`

```
Mage::log((array)$updateFiles);
```

it's returning

```
2014-01-27T13:01:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => core.xml
    ......
    [40] => easylife_test.xml
    [41] => moneybookers.xml
    [42] => local.xml
)
```

here also my layout file is calling but my header link is not displaying.

my `magento\app\design\frontend\easylife\defalut\layout\easylife_test.xml`
code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"></remove>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>Example</label>
                <url>http://google.com</url>
                <title>Example</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>100</position>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Can I know what's wrong this code?

thanks.

Comment: But in your log is present 'easylife_test.xml'. And you tell that your layout file is `magento\app\design\frontend\easylife\defalut\layouteasylife.xml`. Why?

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, sorry I post wrong. now see my question is updated.

Comment: Search in code for `$this->getChildHtml('topLinks');`.
Check if it is present in yours header template file.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, where (which file) should I write this?

Comment: In default magento installation it is located in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\header.phtml

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, only `myaccount,whitelist,mycart,checkout and login` links are comming.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, actually layout.xml file is not calling? can you tell me where is the problem?

Comment: If it is not calling it means that file location is wrong.
magento\app\design\frontend\easylife\defalut\layout\easylife_test.xml. Try to copy it to 'magento\app\design\frontend\base\defalut\layout'

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, if I move to `base\default\layout` then when I update magento it will be override? at that time what can I do?

Comment: Under `base\default\layout` folder create 'easylife' and put easylife_test.xml inside. In modules config.xml change layout defitition from easylife_test.xml -> easylife/easylife_test.xml

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, my question is when I update magento it will be override or not? if i put `base\default\layout` here.

Comment: It depends how you will update magento).
But anyway you can move layout back to magento\app\design\frontend\easylife. But in this case you need to set theme in System->design->themes

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, k move to base it's working but my theme not working. any way thank you see you tomarrow.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is working when copied to `base\default`, as mentioned in comments to your question, then it would appear that your package and theme settings are incorrect.

The file path for layout files can be split up as follows:

```
frontend\{package_name}\{theme_name}\layout\catalog.xml
```

Both these sections can be set-up via the admin section under `System->Configuration->General->Design`

Here you will find two sections:

1. Package
2. Themes

Using your example you could enter the data `easylife` into the package section and can leave all the sections under Themes blank as these will fall back to the `default` option.

The fall-back of packages and themes is stated on the [Magento website](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy) as follows:

1. Look for requested file in:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/custom_package/custom_theme/
   skin/frontend/custom_ package/custom_theme
   ```
2. If not found, look for requested file in:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/custom_package/default
   skin/frontend/custom_package/default
   ```
3. If not found, look for requested file in:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/base/default
   skin/frontend/base/default
   ```
4. If not found, a rendering error will occur.